# » PGP Signature is Invalid

Tags: database, pgp, pacman

I faced with a strange problem about aur and pacman. when i try aur sync or pacman -Syu I get

`error: signature from "Internal email" is invalid error: failed to synchronize all databases (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))`

( i have to mention the pgp signature is not from archlinux its from a private  one which i use it for sign database with)
(it not expired and it's exist completly fine)

i already tried rm /var/cach/pacman/sync/*.db.sig file. it is work for pacman but as soon as i run aur sync the error comes up again.
beside that it seems that i can't sign any package with this signature.

i tried to delete and re add it too.didn't help.

i would appriciate if you can help me with that.

Comment: try removing the sig files from `/var/lib/pacman/sync/*sig` (rather than /var/cache/...), it should work fine

Comment: Thanks Praveen, i did it as well didn't help. more over i even recreat aur from the base. problem still exist